# Finding the conditional density

Tags: probability, statistics

How do I find a conditional density of Y, given X = x and $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$?

$f_{XY}(x,y)=2e^{-(x+y)}$ for $0<x<y$.

I know:
$f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)}$?

And calculated $f_{X}(x)$ to be $2e^{-2x}$

What would the next step be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional density is $e^{x-y}$ for $0<x<y$.

Comment: Can you explain how you got that ? I got $e^{-y+x}$

Comment: Sorry, the 'x' key in keyboard didn't work!